# Is there any functional Test framework in .NET like JFunc

Tags: .net, functional-testing

Is there any functional test framework in .Net like Jfunc [http://jfunc.sourceforge.net/]? I wanted to test wcf service. mstest does not work because it's more like unit test. I wish to execute the test from asp.net web page with out any dependency to mstest. fitnesse and selenium will also not work because it's very difficult to work with hosted ISP and kind of 
too much for what i wanted to test.

Some Requirements

some basic annotation based fixture like [FunctionTest] 
sequencing of functional test, 
single instance,
some way to define functiontest suite, 
and good way to get report of all test passed not just failure

Function test Requirement:

Is the sequence that your tests run in important?
Do you need/want more output than "..F.E"?
Are you struggling with fixtures when what you really want is variables?
Do you need to prepare your suites by hand? (i.e. can't rely on your test suite to be dynamically generated.)

reference
http://jfunc.sourceforge.net/

Comment: What are you looking for in such a test framework? What problem do you need it to solve?

Comment: some basic annotation based fixture like [FunctionTest] ,sequencing of functional test, single instance, some way to define functiontest suite, and good way to get report of all test passed not just failure

Answer (score 0):

It might be overkill for what you're trying to do, but for .NET web apps, I've used Telerik's test studio in the past and found it a quick learn and super effective. The downside, of course, is that it's not free:(

Here's the link:
http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/

Comment: I did try telerik, it was overkill, May be I will try to sleeve up to build my own fwk